# The relationship between the MC's Goal and the climax

Tags: plot, structure

Should the climax come after the MC achieves their goal at a high cost?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Are you trying to understand what a climax is, or when it should occur? A climax of a narrative work is its point of highest tension and drama, or it is the time when the action starts during which the solution is given. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climax_(narrative)) As such, it doesn't occur *after* the story is achieved, right? Or are you trying to ask something else? Surely, the MC doesn't *always* achieve their goal at a high cost, or at all?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are misunderstanding what a climax is. To quote Wikipedia,

> The climax (from the Greek word κλῖμαξ, meaning "staircase" and "ladder") or turning point of a narrative work is its point of highest tension and drama, or it is the time when the action starts during which the solution is given. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climax_(narrative)))

That is to say, **the climax is that part of the narrative when your MC starts their final run towards their goal**. For example, the climax of *The Lord of the Rings* is when Aragorn has his army before the Black Gate, and Frodo is at Mount Doom. It is not after the Ring has already been cast into the fire.

'Climax' is often used as a synonym for 'orgasm'. It is useful to think of just that, to understand what a climax is: orgasm doesn't occur *after* one's finished having sex. It is *the culmination* of having sex. Similarly, the climax doesn't occur when the MC has already achieved his journey - it is the culmination of his journey.